# I'm building a Slack Bot but getting an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, compiler-errors, slack

I was trying to build a Slack Bot in Node but always seem to get this error when I run `npm start` in my terminal :

It shows an error in the Vow.js file. I checked everything twice but can't find the problem. For reference, I was following along this youtube toturial from Brad Traversy [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyyXTIL3Hkw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyyXTIL3Hkw&t=1113s)

```
> alfalfa@1.0.0 start /Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa
> node index.js

/Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:105
            throw e;
            ^

Error: not_allowed_token_type
    at /Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/slackbots/index.js:46:33
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:773:56)
    at callFns (/Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:24:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:75:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Bot instance at:
    at /Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/slackbots/index.js:46:19
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:773:56)
    at callFns (/Users/ayushpathak/Documents/alfalfa/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:24:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:75:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! alfalfa@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the alfalfa@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ayushpathak/.npm/_logs/2021-01-24T08_41_17_374Z-debug.log
```

Here's package.json :

```
  "name": "alfalfa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a slackbot that does, well, everything",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Ayush Pathak",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "slackbots": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here's index.js

```
const SlackBot = require('slackbots');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bot = new SlackBot({
  token : 'I PUT THE TOKEN HERE',
  name : 'alfalfa_beta',
});


bot.on('start', () => {
  const params ={
    icon_emoji : ":eyes:"
  }
bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Initiated!')
})
```

Comment: Discussion [here](https://github.com/slackapi/hubot-slack/issues/584) should help you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

So the token that needed to be added in slackbot is the jwt-token you get from https://api.slack.com/ when you are creating a new bot/app  it cannot be any random string.

You can get the rest necessary details over here https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.permissions.info

[image]